# Unable to Provision Azure VM From Jenkins After Setting up Cloud

Tags: azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, azure-virtual-machine

I'm currently trying to setup Jenkins to provision Azure virtual machines (or container instances) to run integration tests.  After following the instructions on the [VM plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-vm-agents/), I'm not sure how exactly I can get Jenkins to provision an Azure VM from a Jenkins pipeline.  While the plugin claims that it'll provision automatically, I think there's something else I'm missing.  Finding information on how to do this correctly is a bit scarce.

If there's any additional information needed, my project is running in Python and need to use MSSQL.  The project is also being applied against a Github Organization project.

Comment: i've never done this, but did you follow the docs? they clearly say everything is done automatically, check permissions

Comment: Yes.  I did follow the docs.  So, they don't explicitly mention the exact permissions needed to provision the VMs.  I gave the application registration a contributor role

Comment: @4c74356b41, after configuring the cloud to provision VMs, whenever I try to run a build, it always runs the master (the Jenkins server).  Any further way I can troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you follow the docs to provision the Azure VM agent, then you need to check if the VM agent is already created.

Manage Jenkins -> Manage Nodes and clouds:

[image]

And when you create the Item, it will allow you to select the nodes:

[image]

Here you can choose the label that you set for the Azure VM agent. Then the project will run on the Azure VM agent. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/jenkins/scale-deployments-using-vm-agents) is the artcile in Azure.

Comment: So, once you finish configuring your cloud settings, then it'll automatically provision the VM even if you're not running a build?  I can verify that the configuration and VM template are correct, but I'm not seeing a new node being created from the "Manage Nodes and clouds" menu.  What specific permissions does Jenkins need in order for the server to create a node?

Comment: @JosephWoolf Actually, no. Only When you need to run a job on the node, then it will create a new node before running the job. And there are no specific permissions for the Azure service principal, when you create the service principal, it has the Contributor role of the subscription and that's enough.

Comment: Ok, so I only need the service principal to have a contributor role.  That I've done.  Now, my project has a Jenkinsfile, so how exactly do I define the agent so that any build is ran on the provisioned VM and not on the master node (Jenkins server)?

Comment: @JosephWoolf As I said in the answer, you can use the label that you set for the VM agent when you create the job. Then when you build the job, it will run on the VM agent.

Comment: Ahh... Now I see.  I think you can only restrict via label in a Freestyle project.  I'm not seeing the dialog box in the second picture for a Github organization item.  Is there a particular way to restrict it on a Github organization item?

Comment: Ok.  I was able to get it working (though I have another issue that is separate from this one).  I do recommend that you add a part where you need to define the agent label within the pipeline in order to correctly point at the node